# In React, how do I pass arguments into a parent component's handleClick function?

Tags: reactjs

In the main component's render method, I have this line,

```
        <BettingChips onClick={(betAmount) => this.handleClick(betAmount)} />
```

Which corresponds to this function,

```
handleClick(betAmount){
    alert(betAmount);
}
```

However under the child component, I can't seem to pass arguments to the handleClick function,

```
class BettingChips extends Component{

    render(){ 

        return(
     <div> 
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick} value={1} >1</button>
         // ... etc   
     </div>
) 
};
```

I can write this.props.onClick... But I can't write this.props.onClick(1) so that it passes in the integer value of 1 to the parent component. How do I work around that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do this without using arrow function definition inside props (bad for child components performance, as will always be a new function reference [more info here](https://reactarmory.com/answers/when-to-use-arrow-functions#Performance-implications))

Parent class does not need the arrow function defined when passing `onClick` to `BettingChips`, we can do this at the class level instead, using arrow function to lexically bind `this`...

```
class SomeParentComponent extends Component {

  handleClick = (betAmount) => {
    alert(betAmount)
  }

  render() {
    return <BettingChips onClick={this.handleClick} />
  }

}
```

In `BettingChips` use event to extract the `value` from the target of the event (the button that was clicked), so you don't need to use arrow function with amount as parameter

```
class BettingChips extends Component {

  onClick = (e) => {
    this.props.onClick(e.target.value)
  }

  render() { 
   return(
     <div> 
       <button onClick={this.onClick} value={1}>1</button>
       // ... etc   
     </div>
    ) 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple. Just change

```
<button onClick={this.props.onClick} value={1} >1</button>
```

to

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.onClick(1)} value={1} >1</button>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This must work for you:

```
class BettingChips extends Component{

render(){ 
 return(
   <div> 
      <button onClick={() => this.props.onClick(1)} value={1} >1</button>
      // ... etc   
   </div>
  ) 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to create a new function in your child component and call your parent function from `props` there. This is useful if you need to perform some more complicated logic when the button is clicked. Here is a code example:

```
class BettingChips extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }
    onClick() {
        // do something else or prepare parameters for parent's `onClick`
        this.props.onClick(1);
    }
    render(){ 
        return(
             <div> 
                 <button onClick={this.onClick} value={1}>1</button>   
             </div>
         );
};
```